# Android widget manifest

Tags: android, widget, manifest

Why does the following manifest not install a widget icon on the widget menu?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.stackwidget">
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="13" android:minSdkVersion="13"/>
<application android:label="StackWidget">
    <receiver android:name="StackWidgetProvider">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/stackwidgetinfo" />
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="StackWidgetService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS"
        android:exported="false" />
</application>
```

A little more info, the apk is installed and shows up in the Settings-Applications list, but the not in the Widgets or Apps menu list.

(also, I have no idea why the closing  tag is not showing up in the code section above)

These are the logs:

```
[2011-11-11 21:35:17 - StackWidget] Android Launch!
[2011-11-11 21:35:17 - StackWidget] adb is running normally.
[2011-11-11 21:35:17 - StackWidget] No Launcher activity found!
[2011-11-11 21:35:17 - StackWidget] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2011-11-11 21:35:17 - StackWidget] Performing sync
[2011-11-11 21:35:21 - StackWidget] Uploading StackWidget.apk onto device '28841c9415fd157'
[2011-11-11 21:35:21 - StackWidget] Installing StackWidget.apk...
[2011-11-11 21:35:22 - StackWidget] Success!
[2011-11-11 21:35:22 - StackWidget] \StackWidget\bin\StackWidget.apk installed on device
[2011-11-11 21:35:22 - StackWidget] Done!
```

I can only assume that:

"The launch will only sync the application package on the device!"

is the problem, but how to solve this seems to be beyond my research capabilities.

---

ok, I admit that I have clarified this post with edits since the "undervote". I hope these edits have added significant information to the original code snippet (which has not been changed). The bottom line is, this is code I downloaded directly off the android sample web site, so my question is:

If you are so bold as to undervote this question, answer why:
1) under researched
2) not clear
3) useless

### otherwise, please just answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just glancing at this I see no reference to the icon.

application android:icon="@drawable/????

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help. The widget icon is set in <appwidget-provider> android:previewImage="@drawable/preview" </appwidget-provider> which is defined in the android:resource="@xml/stackwidgetinfo" of this manifest

Comment: It turns out this is very close, the android:icon needs to be set in the @xml/stackwidgetinfo resource. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Marcus, I found the problem. The stackwidgetinfo.xml resource needs the following entry:

```
android:icon="@drawable/????"
```

btw, at the time of this writing, this is a bug in the StackWidget sample code found here:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/StackWidget/res/xml/stackwidgetinfo.html